# Parse subset of Python grammar

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, grammar

We are working on a tool to validate user configurations. Invalid configurations will be described in some text file or json file in following form:

```
case1: if something > 5 and something.else != 10
case2: (if a <= 3 or a >= 5) and b == 10
```

In case the if statement evaluates to true, the configuration is invalid. We used SLY module to create a lexer and parser to parse this sentence and check, whether it's valid or not. After thinking a bit more, we realized, that instead of writing our own grammar, it would be interesting to use a subset of the Python grammar - let's say expressions, bool operators and few others, but not the complete set, as we don't want and need to incorporate support for functions, classes and many more. The reason for such approach was, that we are writing our tool in Python, so it could cooperate nicely.

I've checked the ast module, however, I've a feeling, that the grammar is tightly coupled with it. If I understand it correctly, the Python parser is not generated automatically using some existing parser generator based on a grammar, right? The parser is "hard coded". Or em I wrong?

Is there "simple" way of doing this?

In general, we are looking for a parser generator, which generates the parser for a subset of Python grammar, but I'm afraid to cover part of the Python grammar, we would need to write the grammar by ourselves and based on it generate a parser. Is my assumption right?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not making your DSL _actually Python_? Why go through the parse route where you actually have to understand a programming language rather than use an existing one? Python was built to be a scripting language and does this quite nicely. It also has pretty strong metaprogramming capabilities that you can use.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you suggest to use Python code directly in there and use some eval( ) or something like that on that string later on in the code, right? That's actually a good point.
Initially we didn't want to use advanced stuff, just comparisons etc., that's why we thought about "own" grammar or a Python subset.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: they are already using Sly, [David Beazley's newer parser generator](https://www.dabeaz.com/talks.html#reinventing-parser-generator).

Comment: @STRenegade: the python parser is generated with a parser generator, but it's not really independently usable. As if Python 3.9, [a new PEG-based parser-generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/) is being used, allowing a simpler grammar. You might be able to use some of that grammar.

Comment: @rici good point. TIL, I'll check that conference talk out (deleted my comment)

Comment: @STRenegade yes - exactly

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: The only drawback I see is the full grammar. Anyway, thank you all for the valuable inputs! This helped a lot.